# Inverse image of codomain example

Tags: functions

I have a doubt that I imagine to be trivial. How could I establish the image and the inverse image of the function below?

$$\mathit{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\mathit{f}(x)=\sin(e^{|x|})$$

I would have to look at your graphical representation? or is there a more immediate way to do this? My question was clear?

Comment: Is the "domain image" the same thing as the image?  What do you mean by the inverse image of the domain?  Should that be "codomain?"  Also, what have you tried to do on this problem?  Can you write down in less technical terms what you're trying to find?

Comment: I couldn't establish which is the image and the inverse image of that function. The only way I found it was by looking at your chart, but clearly it's a very inaccurate way

Comment: Your function is a composition of two functions, $sin(x)$ and $e^{|x|}$. To figure out the image you need to figure out the image of $e^{|x|}$ and then where $sin(x)$ takes that

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it without graphing it.  Take it step-by-step.  What is the image of $e^{|x|}?$  It's the set $\{e^x\mid x\ge 0\} =[1,\infty).$  What is the range of the $\sin$ function on this interval?  It's $[-1,1],$ so that's the image of the composite function.

Now what is the inverse image of the codomain?  Write down what this means, and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's inverse image